# How to restore MOSS 2007 intranet site into share point 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, migration, sharepoint-2010

I have my company intranet portal in Moss 2007,i need to implement it into 2010,What are the possible way to do this.is that possible to restore the content data base in 2010 portal.

Comment: Your question is too broad - read about the upgrade process here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx. Then provide more information (how is the portal configured? any layout customizations? any custom solutions or site templates installed?) and make the question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do a Content Database restore to the 2010 Server. But keep in mind as **Marek** quoted success of your upgrade dependes on what are the changes & customization you have applied to the 2007 version of the site.

But to quote in simple steps.

1. Install SharePoint SP2 to your 2007 Environment.
2. Run Pre-upgrade checker & note all points on what is supported and what is not.
3. Import all your 2007 solutions to 2010 version and deploy to the new system.
4. Take a backup of 2007 DB, restore it to 2010 DB server.
5. Create a new 2010 Web Application.
6. Go to Content Database of 2010 WebApplication and remove the Content database.
7. Use STSADM command addcontentdb to attach you 2007 DB, which will automatically be upgraded. Check the log file, correct any errors, start again
8. Do these steps in your test environment & once you are happy move to production.

**Note: You need a proper planning on upgrade, go through the belo article fully before you start the process.**

[Upgrade approach](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx)